# Uniform distance

Tags: analysis

Uniform distance: $|f-g|_A= \sup \{ f(x)-g(x), x \in A\}, f(x)-g(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in A$

Find the uniform distance of $f(x)=x, g(x)=1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

My attempt is to take cases for $x$.

$x \geq 1: h(x)=x-1 \geq 0, h'(x)=1$,so $h$ increasing, $\sup \{h(x) | x \geq 1\}= \lim_{x \to +\infty} (x-1)=+\infty$

$x \leq 1:h(x)=1-x \geq 0, h'(x)=-1<0$,so $h$ decreasing, $\sup \{h(x) | x \leq 1 \}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} (1-x)=+\infty$

uniform distance=$+\infty$

Make my thoughts sense?

Comment: It is standard to define the uniform distance as
$$
\| f-g \|_A = \sup\{ |f(x) - g(x)| : x \in A\}
$$
which doesn't require the inequality $g \leq f$.

Comment: What do I have to do to find $\sup \{|x-1|: x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you can notice that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$ by taking $x = n+1$ you get $|x-1| = n$. From this you know that $\sup\{|x-1| : x \in \Bbb{R}\} \geq |(n+1)-1| = n$. Since $n$ was arbitrary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcomplicated your answer, if you ask me. For $x\geq 1$, it is clear that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x-1 = \infty$ and there is no need for calculating $h'$.

As for $x\leq 1$, since for $x\leq 1$ the statement $f(x)-g(x)$ does not hold, there is some confusion. In your definition, actually, you demand that $f(x)-g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in A$ which is not true for $f$ and $g$ in your case.

Comment: Can we not find the uniform distance for $x \leq 1$ ?

Comment: Is it better to take the absolute value of $f-g$,or does it make no sense ?

Comment: I am saying that your definition of the distance is confuzing. You say that it is the supremum of $f(x) - g(x)$ over all $x\in A$ where $f(x)-g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in A$. But what about if "$f(x)-g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in A$" does not hold?

Comment: In the textbook,at the definition it is $|f(x)-g(x)| \geq 0 \forall x \in A$,the professor might accidentally have forgotten the absolute value.

Comment: Can I find the uniform distance,with the new definition?

Comment: That is probably the case. In any case, it is trivial to see that the value $|x-1|$  can be arbitrarily large for large (or small) values of $x$ so the supremum is $\infty.$

Comment: So,do we take the limit $x \to +\infty$ and $x \to -\infty$  or only  $x \to +\infty$?

Comment: It is enough to show that one of the limits is $\infty$, since $\sup A \leq \sup B$ for $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: I didn't get it.What is $A$ and $B$ in the case now?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In general,do we always take only $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |f-g|$ to find the uniform distance?

Comment: Absolutely not. For example, the uniform distance between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ exists, while the limit of $|\cos x - \sin x|$ does not.

Comment: A ok....Thanks!